# How does the Mac OS X Finder recognize a PNG file?

Tags: macos, png, mime, finder

I have a file which was originally named 'foo' in the Finder.  If I 'get info' for the file, the Finder recognizes it as "Kind: Plain text".  If I rename the file as 'foo.png', Finder then recognizes it as "Kind: Portable Network Graphics image".  If I rename the file as 'foo', Finder still recognizes it as "Kind: Portable Networks Graphics image" (not plain text like I expected).

How is Mac OS X recognizing the file kind?

Answer (score 2):

Magic numbers in the file is usually how it works.  A PNG file, for example, has a header to identify it as PNG and not some other file format.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) has some more info.

Answer (score 1):

Because *NIX systems (like Mac OS X) don't rely on extensions to recognize file types. They rely on something called Magic Number (if I remember well), that is, they search for common patterns found in those types of file (e.g headers, tags, metainfo etc.) and they recognize them.

Comment: Actually, that's *not* true of Mac OS X. It uses a complex system of looking at extensions and other metadata that, since OS X 10.3, has been combined into a hierarchy of Uniform Type Identifiers (http://developer.apple.com/macosx/uniformtypeidentifiers.html) something Apple has been tweaking in every release since then.

Comment: New URL for @NedDeily's helpful link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it works, but I can imagine that until you renamed the file to `foo.png` Finder didn't know and didn't care what type it is. But after you've renamed it Finder stored it's type somewhere (`.DS_Store` perhaps?) with the inode ID so it could recognize this file even after you rename it again.